# Points dataset legend to polygon dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend, layer-file

I'm working with ArcMap 10.5.1

I have a point dataset in a gdb, with a particular legend. The color in the legend represent the area of effect that intersects that point. I also have a polygon dataset, in the same gdb, that represents said areas of effect. The coincident field with the area of effect ID is present in both datasets.

In my layout I'd like to showcase the points with a different color depending on the area of effect they belong to, and then, below this layer, the areas of effect dataset with the same colors but some transparency. The colors were randomly generated in the symbology options.

I exported my point dataset legend to a lyr file to transfer it to the polygons, but it does not work because of the different types of geometry. And entering the colors manually would be too much work.

Is there any way I can transfer the legend from one dataset to the other?